# Prisma returns records in update order instead of insertion order

Tags: postgresql, prisma

Simple case:

1. I fetch records using `findMany({})` - I get records in order [`1`, `2`, `3`].
2. I edit record `2` using `update`.
3. I fetch all records again and I get [`1`, `3`, `2`].

How am I supposed to return the records in db (insertion) order **without** introducing any additional timestamp fields and/or doing any ordering in general. I know that there are no order guarantees by default in relational sets but the default ordering by update timestamp was quite unexpected for me.

Comment: This _is_ the expected behaviour. You can never rely upon the order of returned records unless you use an `order by` clause. No such thing as default order exists.

Comment: This I understand. I am lost on the ordering by update timestamp aspect.

Comment: Well, this is a matter of internal implementation that you should never rely upon.

Comment: Two reasons for random nature of items return without `order by`. 1) According to the relational theory rows are unordered.  2) Postgres uses a delete/insert process for updates. Thus, in a since the insert order has changed. In short if you must not introduce a ordering column you cannot have a deterministic result.